# How to read regex2dfa output

Tags: regex, dfa, nfa

I am messing around with this regex2dfa library -> https://github.com/kpdyer/regex2dfa, using the command `./regex2dfa -r "(abc+)+"`

This returns

```
0 2 97 97
1 3 99 99
2 1 98 98
3 2 97 97
3 3 99 99
3
```

Looking at this

https://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/spring01/notes/node8.html

and using the DFA generated here for the regex (abc+)+

http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa

I can't seem to figure out how to go from the diagram, to the transition table(?) that the regex2dfa tool is outputting.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just guessing, but "Transition from 0 to 2 if 97 ≤ c ≤ 97"?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am assuming a, b, c are 97, 98, 99 respectively